# Balloon plots with colours based on value and with value number inside the dots

Tags: r, balloon

```
structure(list(Patients = c("LT2", "LT2", "LT2", "LT2", "LT2", 
"LT2", "LT2", "LT2", "LT2", "LT2", "LT3", "LT3", "LT3", "LT3", 
"LT3", "LT3", "LT3", "LT3", "LT3", "LT3", "LT4", "LT4", "LT4", 
"LT4", "LT4", "LT4", "LT4", "LT4", "LT4", "LT4", "LT5", "LT5", 
"LT5", "LT5", "LT5", "LT5", "LT5", "LT5", "LT5", "LT5"), Cell_type = c("CD3 T cells", 
"CD4 T cells", "CD8 T cells", "NKT cells", "CD14 monocytes", 
"CD19 B cells", "CD56 dim NK cells", "CD56 high NK cells", "Eosinophils", 
"Neutrophils", "CD3 T cells", "CD4 T cells", "CD8 T cells", "NKT cells", 
"CD14 monocytes", "CD19 B cells", "CD56 dim NK cells", "CD56 high NK cells", 
"Eosinophils", "Neutrophils", "CD3 T cells", "CD4 T cells", "CD8 T cells", 
"NKT cells", "CD14 monocytes", "CD19 B cells", "CD56 dim NK cells", 
"CD56 high NK cells", "Eosinophils", "Neutrophils", "CD3 T cells", 
"CD4 T cells", "CD8 T cells", "NKT cells", "CD14 monocytes", 
"CD19 B cells", "CD56 dim NK cells", "CD56 high NK cells", "Eosinophils", 
"Neutrophils"), Value = c(25.6, 61.8, 27.2, 4.94, 1.92, 11.1, 
7.39, 42.8, 4.39, 42.9, 19.8, 65.3, 29.1, 2.87, 1.68, 1.99, 6.23, 
60.7, 4.7, 61.5, 20.3, 81, 16.2, 0.25, 1.09, 3.3, 7.07, 61.9, 
4.96, 61.6, 29.4, 76.2, 20.8, 1.47, 1.3, 3.92, 11.3, 35.3, 1.18, 
51.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -40L))
```

Hi everyone, I was wondering if anyone could help making balloon plots with colours based on values, and value numbers in the dots. I can't download ggballoonplot in R, even though ggplot2 is updated.

I run the following code, but can only get black balloon plots.

```
Immunoph <- read.csv("LS-Pts_csv.csv", header = T)

names(Immunoph)[names(Immunoph) =="Freq"] <-"Value"
head(Immunoph)

p <- ggplot(Immunoph, aes(x=Patients, y=Cell_type))

p+geom_point(aes(size=Value)) +theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
                                     panel.border =element_rect(colour = "blue", fill = NA, size = 1))
```

I would appreciate any suggestion/help, and sorry for my poor skills in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `color = Value` inside `aes` and add a `geom_text()` call:

```
p <- ggplot(Immunoph, aes(x=Patients, y=Cell_type, color = Value))

p+geom_point(aes(size=Value)) +theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
                                     panel.border =element_rect(colour = "blue", fill = NA, size = 1)) +
  geom_text(label=Immunoph$Value, color="black")
```

Gives you:
[image]

Although if you nudge the text it looks better:

```
p <- ggplot(Immunoph, aes(x=Patients, y=Cell_type, color = Value))

p+geom_point(aes(size=Value)) +theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
                                     panel.border =element_rect(colour = "blue", fill = NA, size = 1)) +
  geom_text(label=Immunoph$Value, color="black", nudge_x = 0.2)
```

[image]